# Function to delete multiple specific rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

When I clean my data, which is called `total`, I need to delete rows where Column `V9`'s  string length is less than `10`. Is there any function to do this?

I already tried the `subset` function, but I get the error mentioned below:

```
subset(total$V9, str_length < 10)
```

> Error in str_length < 10 :    comparison (3) is possible only for
>   atomic and list types.

Comment: `subset(total, str_length(V9)>=10)` or `total[str_length(total$V9)>=10, ]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

`total[which(nchar(total$V9))>=10,]`

it will return only line where the string length is >= 10

Comment: Am I wrong or is it missing a `=` to have >=10?

Comment: correct, thanks a lot. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can remove **`Multiple Rows`** by **`selecting a subset`**
you can also use subset function with multiple conditions

```
  # remove rows in r - subset function with multiple conditions
 subset(total$V9, your condition) //you can check your conditions here
```

you can select your subset as per your requirement

> Update from **Jogo** Comment

```
subset(total, str_length(V9)>=10) or total[str_length(total$V9)>=10, ]
```